# Bypass error from StDev_P when range has no values

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to handle errors in a program that takes in a set of ranges, and among other items, calculates its Standard Deviation.  Because some ranges passed in are empty, I get a `Run-time error: Unable to get the StDev_P property of the WorksheetFunction Class`.  However, I am having trouble bypassing it. I tried the following, but the error still throws.

```
        set WF = Application.WorksheetFunction
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.IsError(WF.StDev_P(range1)) = True Then
            sd = 0
        Else
            sd = WF.StDev_P(range1)
        End If
```

Comment: Can't you just check to see if the ranges that are passed in are empty?

Comment: You're right. That will do it. Thanks.